# Is a compound delete possible with Android Content Provider?

Tags: android

I would like to delete from a content similar to this pseudo SQL

```
DELETE *
FROM UserDictionary AS T1
WHERE T1.frequency <>(SELECT MAX (T2.T1.frequency )
                      FROM UserDictionary T2
                      WHERE T1.word = T2.word AND T1.locale = T2.locale);
```

Is this possible in one go like this? Obviously I can iterate over a cursor that selects all the rows and then in that loop use `contentResolver.delete`. I suspect it's not possible to do it without a loop, but I thought I would ask.

Comment: Are you developing a ContentProvider or using an existing one?

Comment: Using an existing one. I would like to delete duplicate words from UserDictionary.Words.

Answer (score 0):

A Content Provider could be written to provide this capability.

Because you are using an existing Content Provider you need to check the documentation for that Content Provider.   Scanning the [documentation for UserDictionary](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/UserDictionary.html) I don't see it so you will probably have to write your own loop.